# Referencing a Cell Value for DriveApp.getFilesByName()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm putting together a "processor" to import data from a CSV file exported from a vendor. Everytime we download the file it gets named `export.csv`, but as we download multiple files we end up with names like: `export (20).csv`.

I'm trying to modify this script:

```
function importCSV() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('export (20).csv').next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

But rather than explicitly state the file name "'export (20).csv'" in the script, I'd like to file name to come from a cell/field on my sheet, specifically "ImportedCSV!Q1" which would have the name of the file I want to import.

so instead of:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('export (20).csv').next();
```

I'd like it to pull the file name from cell Q1:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('ImportedCSV!Q1').next();
```

I've hacked together a dozen different ways to do this and I just can't seem to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like that

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ImportedCSV");
 var row = 1;  // row 1
 var col = 17; // col Q

 var value = ss.getRange(row, col).getValue();
 Logger.log(value);  
 
 var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(value).next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oleg and Gabriel! (and to the wonderful Stack Overflow Community)

This is my final script that works based on Oleg's addition:

I wanted to add that this solution works for me because the files I want to import are always exported from my source in the same width (A:N) format so I'm not concerned with "overwriting" cell Q1.

```
function ImportCSVFile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ImportedCSV");
  //the cell reference below has the file name of the file to import (cell Q1)
  var row = 1;  // row 1
  var col = 17; // col Q

  var value = ss.getRange(row, col).getValue(); //This sets the Range to 1,17 and gets the value
  
  Logger.log(value);  
 
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(value).next(); 
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

The Stack Overflow community has been so helpful for me as a small business owner trying to "speed up"/organize processes as we grow our small business and struggle with "little coding" problems.